Transformation from PDE to ODE
The question is pretty straightforward maybe. Lets say we have the following first order PDE
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\Theta=0
$$
with the following transformation $z=x+y$, this can easily be written as first order ODE
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\Theta=0
$$
Initially, we had two DOF for $\Theta$, but with the constrain, we reduce to one DOF.
Now my actual question is, is it always possible to get such constraint for any PDE, to reduce the number of independent variables? For instance lets take the Wave eqn $\Delta \Theta=0$, with $(1+1)$ dim. Is it possible to reduce it into a ODE, with some constraint?

That transformation does not hold. Take $\Theta = x + y$ for example. Then $(\partial_x + \partial_y) \Theta = 1 + 1 = 2 \ne \frac{d}{d (x + y)} \Theta = 1$.

Your transformation is not complete, in that the pair of variables $(x,y)$ should be replaced by another pair of variables. In the present case, the natural choice is given by $z_\pm = x \pm y$. In consequence, the problem $(\partial_x + \partial_y)\Theta(x,y) = 0$ becomes $\partial_{z_+}\Theta(z_+,z_-) = 0$, which is solved by $\Theta = f(z_-) = f(x-y)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function.
The $(1+1)$-dimensional wave equation can be handled in the same manner. Indeed, the same change of variables, namely $z_\pm = x \pm t$, permits to rewrite the equation $(\partial_{xx} - \partial_{tt})\Theta(x,t) = 0$ as $\partial_{z_+z_-}\Theta(z_+,z_-) = 0$, hence $\Theta = f(z_+) + g(z_-) = f(x+t) + g(x-t)$, where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions.
Actually, when dealing with first-order PDEs, it corresponds to the method of characteristics. By the way, the latter can be extended to higher-order differential equations, but then it requires the use of jet bundles.
